# how to play slow motion video using flvplayback component

Tags: actionscript-3

I need help on playing a video in slow motion using flvplayback component of flash. Is there anyway to achieve this functionality using flv component.

How we can achieve this using as3?

Answer (score 0):

I would use getTimer() flash.utils.getTimer() and enterFrame event.

Use this logic for enterFrame (pseudocode) :

```
if(playState){
    pauseVideo()
}else if(getTimer()-previousTime > speed){
    StartPlaying Video
    playState=true;
    previousTime -=speed;
}
```

playstate is a boolean variable, previousTime is Number

This will play one frame, wait for speed milisecond and then play one other frame. speed = 1000/ desired framerate = 32 for 30fps